# Illegal on linked parameter error

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using following Code to dynamically assign first option variable to parameter in crystal Report. Some of the reports works file but some shows following error.

```
ReportDocument rptH = new ReportDocument();
---
 ---
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinitions 
    crParameterdef;

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinition def in crParameterdef)
        {
              if (def.DefaultValues.Count > 0)
              {
  rptH.SetParameterValue(def.ParameterFieldName, def.DefaultValues[0]);
              }
        }
```

But Got the following Error

```
Error in File Minutes 480 28732_29464_{62EFC36F-064E-4941-8761-55F72CFFE8B7}.rpt:
Operation illegal on linked parameter.
```

And When avoid following code got following error.

```
Missing parameter values.
```